# Mapview in BottomSheetDialogFragment dragging very laggy

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-mapview

I have a BottomSheetDialogFragment that contains a layout with a Google MapView like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_heightPercent="40%"/>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_heightPercent="60%"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

However when trying to drag around the map, it will only drag a very small amount before seeming to lose the touch. You can repeatedly move very small amounts. It seems like possibly the BottomSheet is intercepting the TouchEvent. In this particular case, the BottomSheet is not able to be dismissed so I don't need the touches to be intercepted at all. Any ideas to provide smooth dragging and pinching for zooming?